# Nonassociative reductions with Java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, reduce, java-stream

As you may know, the Java Stream API handles reduction operations that are associative; this allows for the possibility that reduction may be performed in parallel through spliteration.  However, do we have an analogue for reduction operations that are strictly sequential?

Consider this:

```
public interface ExpressionFactory {
    public Expression createExpression(Expression inner);
}

public interface Expression {
    public void evaluate();
}

public class SequentialExpressionFactory implements ExpressionFactory {
    private final List<ExpressionFactory> factories;
}
```

What we want to do is have the implementation of `createExpression()` in `SequentialExpressionFactory` return an `Expression` that consists of starting with the base expression and calling `createExpression()` for each factory, using the output of one as the input for the next.  This is of course, trivially doable with a for-loop, but let's try to consider the use of the Stream API here.

If we try to use Stream API, then we would have to use `reduce()`, but `reduce()` takes a combiner.  Given that `SequentialExpressionFactory` must evaluate each `Expression` *in order*, semantically the notion of a combiner doesn't really make sense.  Of course, using a throwing combiner is not only a code smell, we cannot guarantee that the throwing combiner will never be used (and of course, it leads to brittleness when the reduction operation gives the correct result "some of the time").  Furthermore, the way we have this, this really isn't an associative operation, and the Stream API requires reduction operations to be associative.

Again, given this operation and a need to do what is a reduction operation, is there a (third-party) "sequence" analogue to the Stream API that can do these nonassociative reduction operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not third-party; it's the traditional Java `Iterable` API.  If necessary, you can call `Stream.iterator()` to sequentially iterate over the stream.

Comment: I was hoping for something that could internalize the iteration, as opposed to using `iterator()` (which seems like it makes the use of the Stream API redundant).

I suppose "iterator wrapper" it is, then...

Comment: Nope, there's no way to do that.  Any third-party library that claims to do so will be doing that internally anyway.

Comment: @Kelvin Chung: might be a little late, but of course, you *can* use internal iteration, if you use the `forEachOrdered(Consumer)` method on the stream. Note that even the `Iterator` detour allows internal iteration via `stream.iterator().forEachRemaining(consumer)`…